# Folded Parallelgram Area Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

we are trying to solve this problem shown in the attached capture:

[image]

Having very little background on this, I am not sure how to proceed in solving this problem and any hints or solutions would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know how to find area of a triangle?

Answer (score 1):

Let longer side be $a$ and shorter side be $b$ then area of the original parallelogram is $a\cdot h$, area of the folded parallelogram is $b \cdot h$ where h is height. Area of the shaded area after the first fold is $a\cdot h- b \cdot h$. Thus, $\Large{\frac{(a-b)h}{ah}=\frac{3}{8}}$ or $b=\frac{5}{8}a$. So the first shaded parallelogram has sides $\frac{5}{8}a$ and $\frac{3}{8}a$. 
We can set $a=8$ without a loss of generality. 
Then the original parallelogram has sides $8$ and $5$, the first shaded parallelogram has sides $5$ and $8-5=3$ and the second shaded parallelogram has sides $3$ and $5-3=2$. The ratio of areas of the second shaded parallelogram and the first shaded parallelogram is $\frac{2}{5}$ (both have the same height). The answer to the puzzle is $\Large{\frac{3}{8}\cdot \frac{2}{5}=\frac{3}{20}}$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and for the process.  So I did get to the part where b = (5/8)a.  However, I can't seem to find the height of the smaller parallelogram on the second fold, which would allow me to proceed to finding the ratio of the area of the smallest shaded parallelogram in Fig. 3 to the area of the shaded parallelogram in Fig. 2.  Really sorry as problems like these really get us confused.  Thank you.

Comment: @RCWong: I updated the answer